# IE10 and IE11 saturate filter

Tags: css, internet-explorer, filter

I have a problem. I am using CSS filter saturate on my website. By default, images are saturate to 40%, a on hover they are saturate(100%). It is really simple, and it works on all browsers I need except IE11. I really need it to work on IE11, it can be both css or javascript solution.

Currently I have something like this:

```
-webkit-filter: saturate(40%);
-moz-filter: saturate(40%);
-o-filter: saturate(40%);
-ms-filter: saturate(40%);
filter:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' ><filter id='saturate40'><feColorMatrix in='SourceGraphic' type='saturate' values='0.4' /></filter></svg>#saturate40");
      filter: saturate(40%);
```

And on hover this:

```
filter: saturate(100%);
-webkit-filter: saturate(100%);
-moz-filter: saturate(100%);
-o-filter: saturate(100%);
-ms-filter: saturate(100%);
filter:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' ><filter id='saturate100'><feColorMatrix in='SourceGraphic' type='saturate' values='1' /></filter></svg>#saturate100");
```

Comment: CSS filters aren't supported by IE10/11. Perhaps `canvas`....but you'll have to do more research on that.

Comment: IE is why we can't have nice things http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Comment: We can have nice things....just use a supporting broswer. They *want* you to use Edge.. :)

Comment: Well I know I cant use CSS filters, but there must be some solution! I have tried canvas, but after that, images are no responsive, so that is not what i need. I have found page which says IE11 support svg filters, but only if you give <image> tag in it. But I have no idea how hover should work with it. :(

Comment: Even the 'official' polyfill for CSS Filter doesn't support IE10/11 https://github.com/Schepp/CSS-Filters-Polyfill
Also, why is this downvoted? This is a genuine, proper question

Comment: It certainly *a* question, a *good* one is debatable. It's a problem-dump and not much else,

Comment: I was able to write an javascript solution for this. Would it be useful for someone still now? If yes, i will release that.

Comment: @shitwithcode it would be useful even today.

Answer (score 1):

Old post but I'm looking to do something similar with the invert filter for accessibility. SVG will work with filters for IE10+. I have a working demo for inverting. I'm sure it could be adapted to saturate the image.

[jsfiddle.net/lylel](https://jsfiddle.net/LyleL/e3nyuk4k/)

## HTML

```
<svg id="svg-image-invert">
   <image id="svg-image" width="150" height="150" xlink:href="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/large-black-icons/512/Zoom_search_find_magnifying_glass.png" />
   <filter id="invert">
   <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="
         -1 0 0 0 1
          0 -1 0 0 1
          0 0 -1 0 1
          0 0 0 1 0" />
   </filter>
</svg>
```

---

## CSS

```
#svg-image:hover {
   filter: url(#invert);
}
```